# two column beamer/sweave slide with grid graphic

Tags: r, latex, ggplot2, beamer, sweave

I'm trying to make a presentation on ggplot2 graphics using beamer + sweave. Some slides should have two columns; the left one for the code, the right one for the resulting graphic. Here's what I tried,

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/texmf/tex/latex/Sweave}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}% AMS standards
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\SweaveOpts{pdf=TRUE, echo=FALSE, fig=FALSE, eps=FALSE, tidy=T, width=4, height=4}

\title{Reproducible data analysis with \texttt{ggplot2} \& \texttt{R}}
\subtitle{subtitle}
\author{Baptiste Augui\'e}
\date{\today}
\institute{Here}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Some text to show the space taken by the title}
\begin{columns}[t] \column{0.5\textwidth}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 
\column{0.5\textwidth}  
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
<<fig=TRUE>>=
grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="slateblue"))
@
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Some text to show the space taken by the title}
\begin{columns}[t] 
  \column{0.5\textwidth}
<<echo=TRUE,fig=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
p <- 
qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=cyl) + 
  theme_grey(base_family="Helvetica")
@
\column{0.5\textwidth}  
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
<<fig=TRUE>>=
print(p)
@
\end{figure}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And the two pages of output.

[image: first page]

[image: second page]

I have two issues with this output:

- the echo-ed sweave code ignores the columns environment and spans the two columns
- the column margins for either graphic are unecessarily wide

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- As for the first question, the easy way is to set `keep.source=TRUE` in SweaveOpts. For more fancy control, see `fancyvrb` and FAQ #9 of Sweave manual.
- The width of the figure can be set by `\setkeys{Gin}{width=1.0\textwidth}`

here is a slight modification:

```
... snip ...

\SweaveOpts{pdf=TRUE, echo=FALSE, fig=FALSE, eps=FALSE, tidy=T, width=4, height=4, keep.source=TRUE}

\title{Reproducible data analysis with \texttt{ggplot2} \& \texttt{R}}

... snip ...


\begin{document}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=1.1\textwidth}

... snip...

<<echo=TRUE,fig=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
p <- 
  qplot(mpg,
        wt,
        data=mtcars,
        colour=cyl) +  
  theme_grey(base_family=
             "Helvetica")
@
```

[image]