# two-column layouts in RStudio presentations/slidify/pandoc

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown, slidify

I'm trying to come up with a good system for generating slides and accompanying handouts. The ideal system would have the following properties:

- beautiful in both presentation (PDF/HTML) and handout (PDF) layouts (handouts should have room for taking notes)
- embedded R chunks, figures, other JPG/PNG pictures, etc.
- easy to compose
- build using command-line tools
- bibliography support
- `pandoc` slide separator format (automatically generate a new slide after headers of a specified level) is preferred
- I can live with a little bit of additional processing (e.g. via `sed`), but would prefer not to write a huge infrastructure
- **two-column layouts**: there is a [SO post on how to get multi-column slides from pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142134/slides-with-columns-in-pandoc), but it is LaTeX- rather than HTML-oriented.
- ability to adjust sizes of embedded images (other than R-generated figures) and column widths on the fly

Here's what I've discovered so far about the various options:

- *Slidify*:

  - doesn't do `pandoc` slide separator format, although [there is a workaround](https://github.com/ramnathv/slidify/issues/15%E2%80%8E)
  - the suggestion for creating handouts is to print to PDF; I'd like to leave room for notes etc. (I could probably figure out a way to do that using something like [PDFtk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) or `psnup` ...)
- `RStudio` presentations (`.Rpres` files):

  - does lots of things nicely, including multi-columns with specified widths
  - doesn't support `pandoc` slide separator format
  - I can't figure out what's going on under the hood. There is [RStudio documentation](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/r_markdown) that describes the translation process for regular HTML, but it doesn't seem to cover the R presentation format (which isn't quite the same). (I have previously invested some effort in [figuring out how to get RStudio-like output via pandoc](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/misc/pandoc_diffs.html) ...), which means I can't generate slides etc. from the command line.
- [RStudio's Development Version](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/preview) (as of March 2014) comes bundled with Pandoc and version 2 of `rmarkdown`. It addresses many of the above issues with the `.Rpres` format.
- `pandoc`: may be the only markdown-translator that has features such as footnotes, bibliography support, etc..  I can also use `pandoc` to generate LaTeX using the [tufte-handout class](http://code.google.com/p/tufte-latex/), which meets my criteria of beauty.

  - Unfortunately, it seems not to have built-in two-column format support. [Yihui Xie's HTML5 example](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/slides/) doesn't show any two-column examples, and it claims (on slide 5) that clicking the "Knit HTML" button in RStudio is equivalent to `pandoc -s -S -i -t dzslides --mathjax knitr-slides.md -o knitr-slides.html`, but it doesn't seem to be ...
- LaTeX/beamer: I could simply compose in `Rnw` (knitr-dialect Sweave) rather than R markdown to begin with.  This would give me ultimate flexibility ...

  - despite many years of LaTeX use I do find LaTeX composition more of a pain than markdown composition.

After all that, my specific question is: *what's the best (easiest) way to generate a two-column layout for HTML output*?

Any other advice will also be appreciated.

Comment: Slidify can do handouts using custom layouts, which are straightforward to write. If you can point me to an example of the type of handout you are looking for, I can post a short example. I am also in the process of figuring out an automated solution to print to pdf, and hopefully will get there in 2014 :)

Comment: Slidify uses the `markdown` package from CRAN, but I am making modifications which will allow a user to switch between `pandoc` and `markdown` for conversion to HTML.

Comment: So, as suggested below, I really just want an equal-width (by default: ideally adjustable-width) plain, two-column table.  In principle one could do two-column text in this format, but I always use it for text in the left column and a picture in the right column ... it does sound like slidify+pandoc would be close to my perfect solution.

Comment: Should you generalize question to include also beamer pdf presentation? I realized that was not originally asked altough I find solution to problem(from another forum) which have been related to that.I think it is not worth of writing that answer to separate question.

Comment: It looks like there might be some good stuff here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I now have what I think is a reasonable solution that should apply at least to `ioslides`-based solutions, and maybe (?) to other HTML5-based formats.  Starting [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns/breaks.html), I added

```
<style>
div#before-column p.forceBreak {
    break-before: column;
}
div#after-column p.forceBreak {
    break-after: column;
}
</style>
```

to the beginning of my document; then putting `<p class="forceBreak"></p>` within a slide with `{.columns-2}` breaks the column at that point, e.g.

```
## Latin hypercube sampling {.columns-2}

- sample evenly, randomly across (potentially many) uncertain parameters

<p class="forceBreak"></p>

![](LHScrop.png)
[User:Saittam, Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LHSsampling.png#/media/File:LHSsampling.png)
```

There may be an even better way, but this isn't too painful.

@ChrisMerkord points out in comments that

```
.forceBreak { -webkit-column-break-after: always; break-after: column; }
```

worked instead (I haven't tested ...)

Comment: This didn't work for me, but using `.forceBreak { -webkit-column-break-after: always; break-after: column; }` did. Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: Where did you put the .forceBreak line?

Answer (score 35):

This is an old Q, but I was recently plagued by a similar question, here's what I found:

Using the RPres format, two columns can be specified like so ([details](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486468-Authoring-R-Presentations)). Note that RPres can only be converted to HTML by clicking a button in RStudio, there doesn't seem to be any command line method, which is a bit annoying. Despite, that I'd say it is currently the simplest and most flexible method for getting slide columns with markdown:

````
=== 

Two Column Layout  
===

This slide has two columns

***

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

Some flexibility is afforded by adjusting the column proportions:

````
===

Two Column Layout  
===
left: 30%
This slide has two columns

***

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

With rmarkdown we can get two columns, but with no control over where the break is, which is a bit of a problem:

````
---
output: ioslides_presentation
---


## Two Column Layout  {.columns-2}

This slide has two columns


```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

[image]

We can also mix markdown and LaTeX in an Rmd file using the `beamer_presentation` format in RStudio to get two columns like this, but can't run any code in either column, which is a limitation:

```
---
output: beamer_presentation
---

Two Column Layout 
-------

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
This slide has two columns
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
If I put any code in here I get an error, see
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202717656-Can-we-have-columns-in-rmarkdown-beamer-presentations-
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

[image]

Seems like a regular Rnw LaTeX doc is the best way to get columns if you want to use LaTex, not this markdown hybrid (cf. [two column beamer/sweave slide with grid graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964750/two-column-beamer-sweave-slide-with-grid-graphic))

In all of the above an image can be placed in an column.

The slidify website has instructions on making two columns here: http://slidify.org/customize.html but it's not clear what has to go into the assets/layouts folder to make it work

Comment: I added workaround for beamer presentation. Error is related to pandoc engine which treats everything between `begin{column]` and `\end{column]` as **TeX**

Answer (score 21):

You can use [`fenced_divs`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fenced-code-blocks) notation or `:::` to create columns or `Two Content layout'. See also [this page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-presentations-with-RStudio#columns) to know more about the notation.

````
## Slide With Image Left

::: columns

:::: column
left
::::

:::: column
right

```{r your-chunk-name, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="your-caption-name"}
knitr::include_graphics("your/figure/path/to/the-image.pdf")

#The figure will appear on the right side of the slide...
```
::::

:::
````

Since `pandoc 2+`, which supports the notation, was implemented in `RStudio v1.2+`, you may need to install [`RStudio v1.2+`](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) first. The installation is easy enough (at least in my case); just download and install `RStudio v1.2+`. In the way of installation, the former version of `RStudio` on your computer will be replaced with the new one without uninstalling it manually.

The `:::` notation can be used even when you knit `.Rmd` files with `beamer_presentation` option, as well as when you create HTML slides. So we don't have to neither mix markdown and LaTeX notation in one file, nor add additional codes any longer: just knit the file as you knit other `.Rmd` with other options.

Comment: Great answer! Is there any way to specify the column width using this approach? Thank you!

Comment: @MiaoCai, `::: {.column width=.3}` this works for setting width (tried in LaTeX)

Comment: see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html

Comment: This is the best answer I've found! Thanks, @carlos-luis-rivera!

Answer (score 9):

There is a [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/vcy7v9Uk95U) for beamer error.

In short: Error is related to pandoc conversion engine, which treats everything between `\begin{...}` and `\end{...}` as **TeX**. It can be avoided by giving new definition for `begin{column}` and `end{column}` in yaml header.

Create mystyle.tex and write there:

```
\def\begincols{\begin{columns}}
\def\begincol{\begin{column}}
\def\endcol{\end{column}}
\def\endcols{\end{columns}}
```

> In the Rmd file use these new **definitions**

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: mystyle.tex
---


Two Column Layout 
-------

\begincols
  \begincol{.48\textwidth}

This slide has two columns.

  \endcol
\begincol{.48\textwidth}

```{r}
#No error here i can run any r code
plot(cars)
```

  \endcol
\endcols
````

And you get:
[image]

Comment: Works great. Just a tiny addition. Always remember _not_ to indent normal markdown text or code chunks. One might be lured to doing this due to the indetation of `\begincols` and `\begincol{}`.

Answer (score 8):

I got an idea from [HERE](http://mattdanner.net/two-column-lists-using-html/), the basic solutions was:

---

````
### Function *inner_join*
. . .

`<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">`
``` {r, echo = FALSE, results = 'markup', eval = TRUE}
kable(cbind(A,B))                                    
```
`</div>`
`<div style="float: right; width: 50%;">`
```{r, echo = TRUE, results = 'markup', eval = TRUE}
inner_join(A,B, by="C")
```
`</div>`
````

---

Comment: This worked for me in rmarkdown isoslides presentation, without quotes (`).

Comment: What do these `...` three dots do?

Comment: It is like `-i` (incremental option) in PANDOC for a only one slide. The `. . . ` is to provide a kind of animation. The lines (or figures) will appear or disappear one by one, after a touch in keyboard arrows. Without `. . . ` the elements of presentation will appear "all at once”.

Answer (score 3):

So far I haven't been able to do better than hacking my own little bit of markup on top of the `rmd` format: I call my source file `rmd0` and run a script including this `sed` tidbit to translate it to `rmd` before calling `knit`:

```
sed -e 's/BEGIN2COLS\(.*\)/<table><tr><td style="vertical-align:top; width=50%" \1>/' \
    -e 's/SWITCH2COLS/<\/td><td style="vertical-align:top">/' \
    -e 's/END2COLS/<\/td><\/tr><\/table>/' ...
```

There are a few reasons I don't like this. (1) It's ugly and special-purpose, and I don't have a particularly good way to allow optional arguments (e.g. relative widths of columns, alignment, etc.).  (2) It has to be tweaked for each output format (e.g. if I wanted LaTeX/beamer output I would need to substitute `\begin{columns}\begin{column}{5cm} ... \end{column}\begin{column}{5cm} ... \end{column}\end{columns}` instead (as it turns out I want to ignore the two-column formatting when I make LaTeX-format handouts, so it's a little easier, but it's still ugly).

Slidify may yet be the answer.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in handout mode, you want the left column to contain the slide text and the right column for notes? Slidify can do this easily using custom layouts. If you can give me an example, I can provide a sample layout and example.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution, but Yihui's `Xaringan` package https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/ works for me. It's based on `remark.js`. In the default template, you can use `.pull-left[]` and `.pull-right[]` . Example: https://slides.yihui.name/xaringan/#15. You only need a minimum tweak on the existing `.rmd` files.