# What are the benefits of using Quarto over RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

[Quarto](https://quarto.org/) is a new open-source scientific and technical publishing system that claims to be the "next generation version of R Markdown from RStudio". I'm an avid RMarkdown user and I have not yet fully understood what are the advantages of using Quarto over RMarkdown. Both seems very similar.

Are there important differences between RMarkdown and Quarto to be aware of?

Comment: Look there: https://yihui.org/en/2022/04/quarto-r-markdown/

Comment: the obligatory [blogpost](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2022-04-we-dont-talk-about-quarto/)

Comment: We've added an [RMarkdown FAQ](https://quarto.org/docs/faq/rmarkdown.html) to help as well.

Answer (score 12):

The key differences, and advantages for me, of using qmd instead of rmd include:

- removes the bookdown pkg as a dependency in my scientific writing, it has simpler and universal [cross-referencing](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html)
- simpler integration with lua filters (I use them for author affiliation details)
- multi-language and multi-engine: Python, R, and JavaScript via integration with [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/), [Knitr](https://yihui.org/knitr/), and [Observable](https://github.com/observablehq/).
- easy two column (and more) [flexible content layouts](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#complex-layouts) for displaying images, code, text, tables, plots, anything
- [Global chunk options](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html) set in YAML, rather than a separate setup chunk
- [Easier to show verbatim chunks](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/execution-options.html#fenced-echo), good for writing tutorials and guides
- [Chunk options](https://quarto.org/docs/computations/r.html#chunk-options) as YAML with the special hashpipe `#|`

Other details I find satisfying:

- <s>fully</s> mostly back compatible with Rmd
- works well in VS Code, Emacs, etc., it's less bound to RStudio as an IDE

Comment: FWIW Rmarkdown worked perfectly fine in Emacs for a decade. That is not new.  I see it mostly as a 'v2' rewrite / rethink / generalization and that should be good enough for new content.

Comment: "fully back compatible with Rmd" isn't an advantage of Quarto *over* Rmarkdown, is it? :-) (TBH the only one of these that appeals to me is the flexible layouts, *if* they really work equally well across all output formats https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847371/two-column-layouts-in-rstudio-presentations-slidify-pandoc ... )

Comment: @BenBolker yes, good point, I've now split my list into 'advantages' and 'details I like'. I feel your pain on the flexible layouts (see my ugly answer to the Q you link to, haha).  Let's see if they can pull it off with quarto. Dirk, yes, to clarify, I mean simpler for non-CS beginners to use with IDEs that are not RStudio, compared to Rmd

Comment: Nice answer. When you say works well in other IDEs, do you mean syntax highlighting? vscode is pretty good at that with rmd, but it lacks the in-IDE cell execution and output preview. Are you saying there are IDEs that can do that with Quarto?

Comment: What are the advantages of setting chunk options via hashpipes (`#| echo = FALSE`) versus putting those options in the chunk delimiters (```{r echo = FALSE}`)? (Besides the pot-friendly moniker.)

Comment: It isn't actually fully back compatible with Rmd.  For example, `rgl` output works better in R Markdown than in Quarto (because Quarto does some really bad simulation of some knitr internals), and https://stackoverflow.com/q/73999697/2554330 is another example where R Markdown features fail in Quarto.

Comment: I don't know if you have also experienced that @Ben, but when I changed from bookdown to quarto my runtime decreased significantly.