# Quarto: Hide toc (table of content) with the Hmisc library

Tags: r, bookdown, quarto

In rmd bookdown files there is the possibility to hide the toc in html output automatically   when not used.

But this behavior does not work with quarto qmd -> html output. Is there something similar available?

Rmd file:

````
---
title: "My Title"
author: "My Name"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2:
    keep_tex: true
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 5
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
require(Hmisc)
```

`r Hmisc::hidingTOC(hidden=TRUE,levels=0)`



# Header 1

## Sub header 1

# Header 2

## Sub header 2
````

Hmisc::hidingTOC() is here the function for auto hiding.

Example how it looks like when expanded:
[image]

Comment: So you do not want to use `toc` when the output format is `html` but show the `toc` when output format is anything else, say, `pdf` ?

Comment: It is an automatic behavior, when you go with the mouse on the toc. You can open and close the menu. The question is only html related.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug or not implemented feature in quarto.

Comment: The `hidingTOC()` function is documented to work on Rmd files, and doesn't mention Quarto.  I think you'll need to update it.  What it does is to insert some Javascript and CSS into the document; you need to figure out what has changed, and make it Quarto compatible.  The source is pretty well documented, so this should be doable.

Comment: Right, `hidingTOC` hasn't been updated in some time.  If anyone wants to work on it the source code is [here](https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/R/hidingTOC.r).

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any mention of quarto support in `{Hmisc}` documentation so far. But using html, css and javascript you can create similar behavior.

**quarto_doc.qmd**

```
---
title: "Table of Contents Button"
format: 
  html:
    toc: true
    include-after-body: 
      file: toc.html
---

# Header 1

## Sub header 1

# Header 2

## Sub header 2
```

**toc.html**

```
<button id="toc-button" onclick="collapseToc()">Contents</button>

<style>

#toc-button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}

</style>

<script>
  function add_button() {
    let sidebar = document.querySelector("#quarto-margin-sidebar");
    let btn = document.querySelector("#toc-button");
    sidebar.prepend(btn)
  }
  
  function collapseToc() {
    let toc = document.querySelector("#TOC");
    if (toc.style.display === "none") {
      toc.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      toc.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  
  window.onload = add_button();
</script>
```

---

[image: Table of Contents Button]

---

Comment: Very nice solution. But the main benefit of the hidden content is, that it takes no space, which is a benefit when you work in an IDE with preview window like Rstudio or VS Code. See the added picture in my question.

Comment: You should have included this at first. Now my answer almost got useless :(

Comment: It can be the base for further improvements. There is obviously actually no support from the Hmisc package.

Comment: To be honest in my opinion, I think you should not mark this answer accepted, because it didn't quite solve the problem, just introduced a possibility (May be!) :-)